# Prove that any state can be generated from a maximally entangled state via LOCC

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$
I have proved that in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}=\mathbb{C}^2\otimes\mathbb{C}^2$, starting from the Bell state $\ket{\Phi^+}=\frac{\ket{00}+\ket{11}}{\sqrt{2}}$ and using LOCC only I can go to any state $\ket{\Psi}=\sum_{i,j=0}^1\Psi_{ij}\ket{ij}\in\mathcal{H}$.

The proof is divided in two steps:

1. $\ket{\Phi^+}$ $\overset{\text{LOCC}}{\longrightarrow}$ $\alpha\ket{00}+\beta\ket{11}\quad$ (for any $\alpha$, $\beta\in\mathbb{C}$)
2. $\alpha\ket{00}+\beta\ket{11}$ $\overset{\text{LOCC}}{\longrightarrow}$ $\ket{\Psi}\in\mathcal{H}$

Now I would like to generalize this proof to two N-level systems instead of qubits, i.e. prove the following

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=1}^N\ket{nn}\overset{\text{LOCC}}{\longrightarrow}\;\sum_{n,m=1}^N\alpha_{nm}\ket{nm}
$$

Any ideas on how to proceed? I have tried induction since I have proved the base case $N=2$, but probably is not the best approach.

Comment: Sorry about the broken kets, in the preview the were displayed correctly. I will try to fix it now.

Comment: Can you explain how you did it for qubits?

Comment: @Iyán You need to show your efforts in more detail, otherwise this smells like do-my-work.

Comment: Other than that: Same as before, but step (1): Go from max. ent. to $\sum \lambda_i |i,i\rangle$, (2) as before.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Okay, okay, I will write it down in detail when I have a bit of time.

Comment: You have to see that people have to put effort into writing an answer - so you should at least put a comparable amount of effort into a question so people see where you are stuck in generalizing this.  (Note that this is std. textbook material, so you should also make clear that you are not just looking for someone to do your work.)

Comment: I understand and I agree with your comment. I will update and complete my question in the following days. This is not part of a problem sheet or homework, I was studying and wanted to prove the general case, which I couldn't find in the textbook I was following.

Comment: I am not saying it *is* homework, but it falls into the category of the homework policy here.